# How to enable security with Confluent Schema Registry Docker Image?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, amazon-ecs, confluent-platform

I am trying to deploy the Confluent Schema Registry into our internal AWS infrastructure (ECS) so that it can be available as a REST API. The complete image is already available from Confluent at:

https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-schema-registry

I have created a Dockerfile for deploying the same with below configuration:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.2.1
EXPOSE 8882
ENV SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="<Bootstrap_server_URL>"
ENV SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME="0.0.0.0"
ENV SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS="http://0.0.0.0:8882"
ENV SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG=true
ENV SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SASL_MECHANISM=PLAIN
ENV SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_SSL
```

I need to enable authentication and authorization for the same service. As per my understanding, the security can be enabled by tweaking the configuration parameters inside the above Dockerfile.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/security.html#configuring-the-rest-api-for-basic-http-authentication

But since I am completely using the image from Confluent, I am not able to understand how can I use the parameters with the image.

Answer (score 0):

You would overwrite them with either the `-e` flag in `docker run` like `docker run -e "FOO=BAR" --rm alpine env` or with yaml in your `docker-compose.yml` file liek

```
---
version: "3.2"
services:
  alpine: env
    command: 
    environment:
      - PGID=BAR
```